# bash script - how to execute command after starting new tmux session

Tags: bash, tmux

For example: start new tmux session, launch webserver (sends log into console), and launch second tmux window for editor.

I had trying do this by different ways - but nothing works.

Answer (score 2):

Take a look at [tmuxify](https://github.com/tonchis/tmuxify) (disclaimer: I wrote it).

It's to automate the launch of `tmux` sessions by defining a layout file with windows, panes and commands.

Answer (score 0):

For commands executions, take a look at this [answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/152740/46313).

But you can also predefining layouts of tmux sessions, try [tmuxinator/tmuxinator](https://github.com/tmuxinator/tmuxinator)
.

Answer (score 0):

You can run shell commands from `~/.tmux.conf`:

```
if-shell shell-command export I_AM_USING_TMUX=1
```

But it often does not seem to work as expected...

The environment variable `TMUX` is set when you run `tmux`. Then you can conditionally run shell commands from `~/.bash_profile`:

```
if [[ ! -z "$TMUX" ]]; then
    # run shell commands
fi
```

Or, you can `export` your own environment variable from `~/.tmux.conf` file (as I already exported one from the beginning) and use it for `if` condition from `~/.bash_profile` again:

```
if [[ ! -z "$GHCHOI_IS_USING_TMUX" ]]; then
    # run shell commands
fi
```